# Исключение при отправке данных в сервис

Tags: android

Пытаюсь отправить данные из Activity в Service. Но при выводе в сервисе полученных из активити данных выбрасывает исключение. Кажется страшно туплю но со вчерашнего вечера ничего лучше не придумал. И еще мне кажется что я опять ступил и не передал данные в сервис. Если ступил подскажите как передать?

Если так передавать то вроде метод запускающий сервис будет каждый раз по новой вызываться что будет в моем случае приводить к остановке онлайн радио и повторному его запуску, а мне так не нужно

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class).putExtra("stream", stream));
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class).putExtra("radio", radio);
```

Во втором активити из основного получаю данные таким образом

Player активити

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity {

    static String stream;
    static String radio;
    static int img;

    PlayerService pService;
    boolean pBound = false;
    private ServiceConnection mConnection;

    final String myLog = "LOG";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        stream = getIntent().getStringExtra("stream");
        radio = getIntent().getStringExtra("radio");

        Log.d(myLog, stream);
        Log.d(myLog, radio);

        mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                PlayerService.LocalBinder binder = (PlayerService.LocalBinder) service;
                pService = binder.getService();
                pBound = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                pBound = false;
            }
        };

        startPlayerService();

    }

    public void startPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Player.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("stream", stream);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("radio", radio);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (!pBound) return;
        unbindService(mConnection);
        pBound = false;
    }
}
```

PlayerService

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {

    public static Context context;
    boolean isPause = true;
    String stream;
    String radio;

    final String myLog = "LOG";

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    private void showNotification() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(Player.stream, "stream");
        notificationIntent.putExtra(Player.radio, "radio");
        notificationIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        closeIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("AAAAAAAAAAAAA")
                .setTicker("BBBBBBBBBBBBB")
                .setContentText("CCCCCCCCC")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "Стоп", pCloseIntent)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
        startForeground(PlayerConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        context = this;

        stream = intent.getStringExtra("stream");
        radio = intent.getStringExtra("radio");

        Log.d(myLog, stream);
        Log.d(myLog, radio);

        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPause = true;
            showNotification();
            //ExoPlayer.startExoPlayer("http://ep128.hostingradio.ru:8030/ep128", this);
            ExoPlayer.startExoPlayer(stream, this);
        } else if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            ExoPlayer.stopExoPlayer();
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        PlayerService getService() {
            return PlayerService.this;
        }
    }

}
```

Выбрасывает такое исключение

```
Process: myapps.onlineradio, PID: 14456
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service myapps.onlineradio.PlayerService@47cfd8f with Intent { act=myapps.onlineradio.action.startforeground cmp=myapps.onlineradio/.PlayerService }: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3314)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:143)
at myapps.onlineradio.PlayerService.onStartCommand(PlayerService.java:60)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3297)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Второе исключение

```
Process: myapps.onlineradio, PID: 6143
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service myapps.onlineradio.PlayerService@137954c with Intent { act=myapps.onlineradio.action.startforeground cmp=myapps.onlineradio/.PlayerService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3314)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:475)
at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java)
at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:437)
at myapps.onlineradio.ExoPlayer.startExoPlayer(ExoPlayer.java:46)
at myapps.onlineradio.PlayerService.onStartCommand(PlayerService.java:66)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3297)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Ругается на строчку Uri streamUri = Uri.parse(url); из класса в котором реализован метод проигрывания радио

Это сам класс где реализован плеер

```
public class ExoPlayer {
    static BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
    static TrackSelector trackSelector;
    static SimpleExoPlayer player;
    //private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;

    public static void startExoPlayer(String url, Context context) {
        if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
        }

        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory streamSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(streamSelectionFactory);

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector, new DefaultLoadControl());
        /*simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(context);
        //Set media controller
        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true);
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
        // Bind the player to the view.
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);*/
        Uri streamUri = Uri.parse(url);
        // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter);
        // Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.

        if (url.contains("m3u8")) {
            MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
            // Prepare the player with the source.
            player.prepare(mediaSource);
        } else {
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
            // Prepare the player with the source.
            player.prepare(mediaSource);
        }

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    public static void stopExoPlayer() {
        player.stop();
    }
}
```

Манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myapps.onlineradio">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Player"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_player"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <service
            android:name=".PlayerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Прекратите удалять свои вопросы после того как вы не получили на них ответ. В прошлый раз я вам советовал посмотреть код из вопроса, который не нашёл. Там было решение вашей проблемы. Теперь выясняется, что это ваш же вопрос и был. Решение вашей проблемы в удалённых вопросах, ответах к ним и комментах.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, вы получаете `NullPointerException` потому что пытаетесь считать данные из интента, которые никак не передавали в сервис.

Во вторых,

> Если так передавать то вроде метод запускающий сервис будет каждый раз
>   по новой вызываться

Не совсем так. Повторный вызов `startService()` для запущенного сервиса просто вызовет метод `onStartCommand()` с новым интентом. Повторного запуска и перезапуска сервиса не будет. Он продолжит работать как и работал.

И в третьих, можно передать сразу несколько `extras` в одном интенте:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("stream", stream);
intent.putExtra("radio", radio);
startService(intent);
```

Таким образом нет необходимости дважды вызывать `startService()`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64138/discussion-on-answer-by-eugeneek------).